# Histogram of date differences

Tags: r

I have a sorted list of descending dates.  How do I get a probability history of the difference between the date on the current line and the date on the next line?  I want to visualize the frequency of how often requests come in.

```
09/11/2011 13:46:39
09/11/2011 13:45:18
09/11/2011 13:44:58
09/11/2011 13:40:02
09/11/2011 13:37:58
09/11/2011 13:36:09
09/11/2011 13:32:31
09/11/2011 13:25:29
09/11/2011 13:24:40
09/11/2011 13:23:48
```

p.s. I've never used R before, so the more code the better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the data

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("
09/11/2011 13:46:39
09/11/2011 13:45:18
09/11/2011 13:44:58
09/11/2011 13:40:02
09/11/2011 13:37:58
09/11/2011 13:36:09
09/11/2011 13:32:31
09/11/2011 13:25:29
09/11/2011 13:24:40
09/11/2011 13:23:48
"), sep="\n")
```

Convert to `POSIXct` date

```
df$V1 <- as.POSIXct(df$V1, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Load `lattice` and plot with the time differences with `histogram`.

The function `diff` is very handy to calculate lagged differences.  You will notice that I also use `unclass`  this is because there is no histogram method for class `difftime`.

```
library(lattice)

histogram(unclass(-diff(df$V1)), xlab="Time difference")
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't want a histogram (that is, not aggregated bins), an alternative is `plot(table(-diff(df$V1)))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer.  Few questions if you don't mind.  First, I get "Warning message: closing unused connection 3 ("\n09/11/2011 13:46:39\n09/11/2011 " as soon as I load lattice.  Any reason for this?  Second, is this why my screen shows 100% at 0?  Finally, my graph shows 100% at 0.  Is it because of the warning or because  -diff(df$V1) shows [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 on mine.

Comment: The "closing unused connection" is a result of `textConnection` and not related to loading `lattice`.  Presumably you will get your data into the system using some other means, so this should not be a problem in normal usage.  I used `-diff(...)` because the dates are in descending order, so `diff(...)` was negative.  If your real data looks different you may have to remove the minus.

Comment: Thanks again.  There's still something up.  I seem to get [1] "0009-11-20 EST" "0009-11-20 EST" "0009-11-20 EST" "0009-11-20 EST" when I want to output df$V1 after I run as.POSIXct on it.  But when I run that as.POSIXct just on the date string itself, it formats fine.

Comment: Got it.  Had to do `strptime(a$V1, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")` instead of POSIXct.  Why, though?  I thought POSIXct was doing that same thing?

Comment: From Jim on the ML:  "'df$V1' is a factor.  Try `as.POSIXct(as.character(df$V1), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`.  You need to convert to a character first."